# C++ return different derived template class based on runtime argument

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have two template class `Derived1` and `Derived2` both derived from `Base`.

I wish `foo` can return `Derived1` or `Derived2` by template instantiation and their type is distinguished by argument `use_int`.

```cpp
class Base {
 public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived1 : public Base {};

template <typename T>
class Derived2 : public Base {};

template <typename Derived>
Base *foo(bool use_int) {
  if (use_int)
    return new Derived<int>();
  else
    return new Derived<float>();
}

int main() {
  Base *obj1 = foo<Derived1>(true);
  Base *obj2 = foo<Derived2>(false);
  delete obj1;
  delete obj2;
  return 0;
}
```

But it won't compile.

```
t.cc: In function ‘Base* foo(bool)’:
t.cc:12:16: error: ‘Derived’ is not a template
   12 |     return new Derived<int>();
      |                ^~~~~~~
t.cc:14:16: error: ‘Derived’ is not a template
   14 |     return new Derived<float>();
      |                ^~~~~~~
t.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cc:18:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo<template<class T> class Derived1>(bool)’
   18 |   Base* obj1 = foo<Derived1>(true);
      |                                  ^
t.cc:10:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class Derived> Base* foo(bool)’
   10 | Base* foo(bool use_int) {
      |       ^~~
t.cc:10:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
t.cc:19:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo<template<class T> class Derived2>(bool)’
   19 |   Base* obj2 = foo<Derived2>(false);
      |                                   ^
t.cc:10:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class Derived> Base* foo(bool)’
   10 | Base* foo(bool use_int) {
      |       ^~~
t.cc:10:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Is this because `Derived1` or `Derived2` is not a complete type? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Derived1` and `Derived2` are templates. If you want to use them as template arguments, you should declare `Derived` as [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter). E.g.

```
template <template <typename> typename Derived>
Base* foo(bool use_int) {
  if (use_int)
    return new Derived<int>();
  else
    return new Derived<float>();
}
```